# Update in php sql does not update database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a script in which you can change the price of an article/item through a form, but it doesn't update my new prices. I think there might be a mistake in my $update, because I don't get any error messages when I change the affected rows (typo on purpose). But I just don't see it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "webauth";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$artikelquery = "SELECT * FROM artikel;";
$artikel = mysqli_query($connection, $artikelquery);
?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Kies een artikel:</br>
<select name="artikel">
<?php
while($artikelrow = mysqli_fetch_row($artikel)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$artikelrow[1].'">'."$artikelrow[1], $artikelrow[3] euro</option>";
}
?>
</select>

</br></br>

Vul de nieuwe prijs van het artikel in:</br>
<input type="number" name="prijs"></br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Verzend">
</form>

<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if($_POST['prijs'] == "") {
        echo 'bla';     
    }
    else {
        $nieuwprijs = $_POST['prijs'];
        $artikel = $_POST['artikel'];
        $update = "UPDATE artikels SET Verkoopprijs ='". $nieuwprijs ."' WHERE Artikelnr ='". $artikel ."';";
        mysqli_query($connection, $update);
        echo 'Artikel '. $artikel .' is aangepast naar '. $nieuwprijs .' euro.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: An error in your SQL query won't trigger a PHP error. You need to look for it explicitly. Check the return value of `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Is `$artikelrow[1]` the article ID ? May be It's the name and the ID is `$artikelrow[0]` ?!

Comment: I think this is not a sql problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very vulenerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Anyway your problem is the table name:

```
$update = "UPDATE artikels SET Verkoopprijs ='". $nieuwprijs ."' WHERE Artikelnr ='". $artikel ."';";
```

Should be

```
$update = "UPDATE artikel ..."
```

Without final s, as your `SELECT` query

```
$artikelquery = "SELECT * FROM artikel;";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd submit this as a comment if I had enough reputation. But here's my suggestion for tracking down SQL errors.

Add this after the UPDATE:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo '<div>DB Error: '. mysqli_error($connection) .'</div>';
```

Also, I'd suggest doing some input validation or escaping so you're not susceptible to SQL injection.